# How does Anydice define OR operation?

Tags: anydice

This is not RPG related question, but since anydice questions are allowed:

Does anyone know how the `|` operation is defined in anydice?

Here is what documentation has to say:

> **Booleans**
>
> In general, the number 0 represents no while any other number – either positive or negative – represents yes. Using this logic, AnyDice allows you to perform boolean operations. This is useful if you like to check multiple conditions. Boolean operations have a lower precedence than all conditions, except for Not, which is a unary operation.
>
> In the examples below, assume that the variable **YES** is set to any number other than 0, while **NO** is set to 0.
>
> **And also**
>
> **YES & YES** yields 1, while any other **YES** and **NO** combination yields 0.
>
> **Or else**
>
> **NO | NO** yields 0, while any other **YES** and **NO** combination yields 1.
>
> **Not**
>
> **!YES** yields 0, while **!NO** yields 1.

There is nothing here that would indicate that the operation is asymmetrical. However given the [following code](https://anydice.com/program/105b9):

```
A:d{0,1}
B:2d{0,1}
output A | B
output B | A
```

We get the following output:

```
"output 1",0.875,0.33071891388307384,0,1
#,%
0,12.5
1,87.5

"output 2",0.375,0.4841229182759271,0,1
#,%
0,62.5
1,37.5
```

Clearly `A|B` is not the same as `B|A`. I understand, that since A and B both dice and not number conversion rules might kick-in. But I still expect the rules to lead to symmetrical results.

What's going on here?

Comment: [Also wierd](https://anydice.com/program/105ba). Iirc A|B|A = A|B

Comment: I don't really have time to test this right now, but I bet it's got something to do with the weird way AnyDice handles comparing numbers and sequences. Or it could just be a bug.

Comment: Also, even by my rather inclusive personal standard, I kind of feel like this question belongs on SO, not here. Maybe it's because it doesn't even *pretend* to be RPG-related.

Comment: Now that I'm home, I tried testing this, but I couldn't reproduce the issue. [The code you linked above](https://anydice.com/program/105b9) gives me the same output (12.5% chance of 0, 87.5% chance of 1) for both `A | B` and `B | A`. The only explanation I can think of (other than some silly mistake like forgetting to click "Calculate" after editing the code) is that this *was* a bug in AnyDice that the developer fixed within the last 13 hours or so.

Comment: I’m closing the question because the output it’s based on can’t be reproduced.

Comment: That was a bug that is now fixed: https://twitter.com/catlikecoding/status/1008372654917726208